# Message counter with jms Hornetq

Tags: jms, counter, hornetq

I want to know the number of messages currently in the jms hornetq, but I only want to turn the counter on for a single JMS queue. I do not want to waste the disk space for all the queue's I have. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Waste disk space with a counter? Are you serious? Anyway, this SO should give a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877258/how-to-find-a-horneq-queue-length

Comment: Use hornetq or jms management api or jmx console (like jconsole in your jdk)!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the message counters for the queues you want through Management.

Look for getMessageCount on the HornetQControl.

If you are using JBoss AS 7 (now known as Wildfly) the console will give you access to that information.