# Simple distributed queue in a jboss cluster?

Tags: queue, cluster-computing, infinispan, jboss-eap-6

I am working on a server that acts as the web service and UI front end in front of another server. Both servers are clustered. One of the features of the UI is tasks that users work on. These tasks are queued up on activemq on the backend server and items are fetched through the frontend server. I want to build a simple in-memory queue so that I can feed these items to the UI as fast as possible. I want to avoid having to configure another activemq server. My current approach is to just distribute the queue using Infinispan, but this feels inefficient. Is there a better way using something already included in JBoss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use standard JMS and the it will go over the HornetQ built into JBoss EAP 6. By default it will use infinispan in-memory.

There is a good article for setting up a clustered queue in AS 7 (EAP 6 should be the same) here:
http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/11/24/clustering-of-the-messaging-subsystem-hornetq-in-jboss-as7-and-eap-6/

In order to monitor the number of items in the queue, you can use JMX:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
        <hornetq-server>
            <clustered>true</clustered>
            <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
            <!-- rest of config here -->
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
```

Once JMX is enabled, you can use HornetQ specific code in order to see the queue length. This question gives an example of that: [How to find a horneq Queue length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877258/how-to-find-a-horneq-queue-length)

Also might be worth noting: JBoss EAP 7 is going to switch from HornetQ to ActiveMQ.

Comment: and that will be replicated across the cluster? Another reason I avoided JMS is that I want to know the size of the queue so I know when to refill it.